# Why does ASP.NET Core invoke Write(), when it needs WriteAsync() to be invoked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement logging of response payloads into a C# ASP .NET service I inherited. To my understanding, it is possible to intercept request and response handling at various stages of processing by writing attributes which inherit from `ActionFilterAttribute` and make the correct overrides and attaching them to controller methods. I managed to wrap the response body with my own implementation (`LoggedStream`) which relays calls of `Write` to the actual body and then performs its own logic thereafter. However, the runtime appears to now treat the response body differently, calling `Write` and then complaining that it should have called `WriteAsync` instead. If I change my invocations to use the async methods in `Flush` and `Write`, everything appears to work. However, why does it invoke the non-async methods when they are the wrong ones, then complain like it was my fault?

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyService.Actions
{

    public class LoggedStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly Stream _stream;

        public LoggedStream(Stream stream, string filePath)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            // TODO: open a file at filePath
        }

        public override bool CanRead => _stream.CanRead;

        public override bool CanSeek => _stream.CanSeek;

        public override bool CanWrite => _stream.CanWrite;

        public override long Length => _stream.Length;

        public override long Position { get => _stream.Position; set => _stream.Position = value; }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            _stream.Flush();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return _stream.Seek(offset, origin);
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            _stream.SetLength(value);
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count); // <- Error here!
            // TODO: Write to file instead of writing to console
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote " + buffer);
        }

        internal void CloseFile()
        {
            // TODO: Close the file
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class LogResponseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            var loggedStream = new LoggedStream(response.Body, "response.log");
            response.Body = loggedStream;

            base.OnResultExecuting(context);
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            var responseBody = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
            if (responseBody is LoggedStream)
            {
                ((LoggedStream)responseBody).CloseFile();
            }

            base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MyService.Actions.LoggedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not simply dump the response to the logging system?

Comment: Because controller returns a list of some objects which gets serialized to json in non-user code, i.e. I have no access to the serialized response.

Comment: More specifically, the controller method in question returns `Task<IActionResult>`, has the `async` keyword (which may be related) and has attributes `[HttpGet]`, `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<Foo>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]`, `[Route("/foos")]` and `[LogResponse]`. Everything before and after is handled by the framework.

Comment: maybe using result filter is best way?

Comment: @MihalBy You are correct. I did override the wrong set of methods. When I call the async methods it totally works now. That part I still do not understand though. Why does framework invoke `Write()` on my wrapper when it clearly requires for `WriteAsync()` to be invoked on the stream? I updated the question.